# Excel macro to print sheets based on multiple values

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I have a sheet with a macro that when i change a value in the cell E5, automatically fill certain fields in *sheet1*, searches and return values from a table on other sheet - *sheetTable*).

My goal now is to select a range of values in a column on *sheetTable* and assign each one of them to Cell E5 on *sheet1*, and print each one.

So let's say I select 3 cells with values: 45, 50 and 66. When I run the macro it will assign 45 to cell E5 and print *sheet1*, then it will assign 50 to cell E5 and print *sheet1* and finally will assign 66 to cell E5 and print *sheet1*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim shape As Excel.shape
' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("e5")


If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then


For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    shape.Delete
Next

InsertPictureInRange Range("f2").Value & Range("e5").Value & ".jpg", _
    Range("c9")
InsertPictureInRange Range("f2").Value & Range("e5").Value & "_1.jpg", _
    Range("i9")

If Range("e5").Value = "" Then Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will run through a selection and paste the values in your cell E5, on Sheet1, and then open the "PrintToFile" dialogue box. From there, you would have to manually input the file location and name.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Selection

Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Set Sheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each Cell In Rng
        Sheet1.Range("e5").Value = Cell.Value
        Sheet1.PrintOut Copies:=1, printtofile:=True, collate:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
    Next Cell
```

This gets you halfway there, at least. Perhaps someone with more experience than I will be able to add how one might input the file location and name using VBA.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It helped a bit, but is not working. this only works in the same sheet. What I need is to select a range on other sheet (the sheet with the table). Also i need the code to print to pdf the sheet1 and naming the pdf file with the value of the value in E5. So if I select 3 cells on the table sheet with values 34,44 and 55. It wil create the following files:34.pdf, 44.pdf and 55.pdf

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for clarifying. I am not sure if there is a way to save a PDF file from Excel outside of using `SendKeys`, which I avoid. I will update my answer to show how you would open a print dialogue for each value. From there you'd have to manually input the file location and name of the sheet. Not a complete answer, I know. I will continue to look for ways to save a PDF to a file from Excel, though.